# Read simulators for Ion Torrent Whole Exome Sequencing

Tags: simulation

I have a aligned BAM file which I want to simulate to generate reads. The platform I used is Ion AmpliSeq Whole Exome Sequencing. I want to know if there are any read simulators for Ion Torrent platform.

Comment: Is this more on topic for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this publication:
Comparison of mapping algorithms used in high-throughput sequencing: application to Ion Torrent data, Caboche et al. BMC Genomics, 2014, 15:264.

Their tool is CuReSim, never used it yet, but I will try it.
Maybe it can help you...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is this a question or an answer?